# how can i delete multiples request at the same time using axios and an array of URL

Tags: reactjs, axios

im doing an app and the first code is working deleting a "task" in my API, but in my app each task have a checkbox input, so, i want to delete all the tasks that are checked.
i used this code to delete single task with a button.

```
  const baseURLtasksId = `https://63cf2168e52f5878299ab5e2.mockapi.io/api/users/${userid}/tasks/${taskId}`
  axios.delete(baseURLtasksId, { done: true }).then()  
}
```

ArrayUrlById this is an array of all the URL's that are checked

```
const deleteAll = () => {
  let ArrayUrlById = []
  ArrayUrlById  = isChecked.map((cId) => {
    let arrayURL = `https://63cf2168e52f5878299ab5e2.mockapi.io/api/users/${userid}/tasks/${cId}`
     
    return arrayURL
  
  })
  console.log(ArrayUrlById); // here i have an array of the URL 
  //  i need to delete now multiples tasks, using an array of URL and sending {done:true} for each one
}
```

i tried with this code, but not working properly, beacuse never delete all of them, even in the console send all the delete request to the endpoint with a 200 status, but after i refresg the website, is not deleting all of them that are checked

```
const deleteAll = () => {
  let ArrayUrlById = []
  console.log('aqui');
  ArrayUrlById  = isChecked.map((c) => {
    let arrayURL = `https://63cf2168e52f5878299ab5e2.mockapi.io/api/users/${userid}/tasks/${c}`
     
    return arrayURL
  
  })
  console.log(ArrayUrlById);
  const requests = ArrayUrlById.map(url => axios.delete(url));

  axios.all(requests)
  .then(responses => {
    responses.forEach(response => console.log(response.data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud9oR.png)

Comment: Can't see anything particularly wrong here other than `axios.all()` is deprecated; you can just use `Promise.all()` instead. If the API responds successfully but doesn't actually perform the delete operation, then this is not a client-side issue

Comment: You seem to have omitted the `{ done: true }` in your `deleteAll()` code. Is that important?

Comment: i added and also changed it with Promise.All, stil working, but not properly, working the same, i checked like 5 inputs but only deleting 3, but in the console  i can see all the ones that i checked delete with 200 status

Comment: Like I said, sounds like a server-side problem